# rabbitmq/java - receive messages by a wish, not by subscribe

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I write consumer for rabbitmq and need receiving messages not by subscribe. I need get it one, work with it, and after work get next one message. It`s some like

```
   while(true){
        String message = consumer.getNext();
        .......
   }
```

In google i found many examples what i need with QueueingConsumer like this

```
    while (true) {
      QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
      String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

      System.out.println(" [x] Consumer : received '" + message + "'");
      doWork(message);

      channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }
```

But QueueingConsumer is deprecated and removed from last rabbitmq java lib. I found only tutorials with subscribe like this https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

Tell please, where cat i find fresh java coode example with functional what i need?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Java land, How open are you to try out spring-boot ?

They have AMQP starters as well, if you need some help to bootstrap.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/

1) Create a worker, who will be subscribed to the queue

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

2) Then bind the worker bean with the queue as per your topology

```
package hello;

// imports omitted for brevity

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    // code omitted for brevity 

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
    }

}
```

If you are new to Spring, it provides with a IoC container. Spring-boot simplifies spring framework configuration/setup (in opinionated way according to some).

Here is the start-up guide:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java guy, so I have no code. But if you set your [prefetch (QoS) limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to 1 then you will only get delivered one message at a time. As soon as you manually ack a message you'll get delivered another straight away.

On your channel, set the prefetch to 1.

```
channel.basicQos(1);
```

So you'll have no loop. Just the standard eventing consumer approach, but you can guarantee that you'll be processing messages sequentially.